# Pandas: Check if value exists in another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm working on Ethereum Fraud detection dataset, 0 denoting normal and 1 denoting fradulent

I have `train_account.csv` as

| account | flag |
| --- | --- |
| a17249 | 0 |
| a03683 | 1 |
| a22146 | 0 |

`transactions.csv` as

| from_account | to_account |
| --- | --- |
| a00996 | b31499 |
| a07890 | a22146 |
| a22146 | b31504 |

I want to make a `test_account.csv`, where only accounts would be given and our task is to find if it is fradulent-1 or normal - 0

| account |
| --- |
| a27890 |
| a03683 |
| a22146 |

Rules I'm following to make below table

- If an account is present in `train_account.csv` `account` column then a flag column with value that is present for that account in `train_account.csv` will be added if not then I go for checking if that account is present in trasnaction['from_account'] or trasaction['to_account'] if yes then add flag value for that account in test_account to be 0 else 1

| account | flag |
| --- | --- |
| a27890 | 1 |
| a03683 | 1 |
| a22146 | 0 |

I'm planning to add a `flag` column based on the above rule, not to add or remove extra rows

PS: I'm beginner and have no clue to do this, Thanks in advance

I tried looping in columns but not sure how to check and add it to the result.
some thing like this:

```py
for i in test_account['account']:
    if i in train_account['account']:
        test_account[i]['flag'] = train_account[i]['flag']
    elif i in trasnaction['from_account'] or trasnaction['to_account']:
        test_account[i]['flag'] = 1
    else:
        test_account[i]['flag'] = 0
```

Comment: Where does a27890 in the first row of test_account come from?

Comment: It was already present in the `test_account.csv` for me to predict, since it was given to me therefore I wrote it to make my point understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
# step 1
train_accounts = train_account['account'].values
test_account['flag'] = np.where(test_account['account'].isin(train_accounts), train_account['flag'], test_account['flag'])
# step 2
accounts = np.append(transactions['from_account'].values,transactions['to_account'].values)
test_account['flag'] = np.where(test_account['account'].isin(accounts), 1, 0)
```

Comment: I'm guessing it will only solve part of a problem i.e accounts which exists on test_account will have value of accounts which exists on train_account, but what about the values which are not present in train_account and depends if it is present in transaction.csv under columns from_account and to_account

Comment: Please explain the second phase. You want to know which accounts appear in either 'from_account' or 'to_account' and....?

Comment: Yes first I want to check accounts from test_account if it exists in train_accounts or not if yes then add a flag value corresponding to that account whatever present in train_account flag column for that account if that is not the case then I want to check if the same account in either present in from_account or to_account from transaction.csv, if yes then add flag value of 1 if not 0

Comment: Does my solution cover this part?: 'first I want to check accounts from test_account if it exists in train_accounts or not if yes then add a flag value corresponding to that account whatever present in train_account flag column for that account'?

Comment: it did partially, but it reduced number of rows which I don't want and also every value in flag column for test_account in NaN

Comment: See updated solution. It is hard to do 100% of what you asked not because it is difficult - but because it is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: You can check my dataset, and what I'm doing from the below link and then I guess you can help me in best ways :)
https://www.kaggle.com/code/prateeklenka/hacktivityfinal

Comment: You will need to take it from here and fine tune the code I wrote above

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, is it now a little easy to understand?

Comment: See new answer!!

Comment: resulted in : IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices, 
I'm checking for this error, but if you have then thanks in advance

Comment: Which line gave this error?

Comment: line 4: 
this one test_account['flag'] = np.where(test_account['account'].isin(train_accounts), train_accounts['flag'], test_account['flag'])

Comment: Corrected it. Copy & paste again

Comment: this time ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6300,) (25198,) (6300,)